# javascript circle moves around a point

Tags: javascript

My element does circling around a point.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDhn4/)

HTML

```
<div class="center-dot">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center-dot {position:relative;top:200px;left:200px;}
.dot {width:3px;height:3px;background:blue;}
.one {width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;background:red;position:absolute;}
.two {width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;background:green;position:absolute;}
```

JS:

```
var one = $('.one'),
    two = $('.two');

var one_start = 0,
    two_start = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    ++one_start;
    var one_css = {
        'left': Math.sin(one_start * 0.0010) * 100 ,
        'top': Math.cos(one_start * 0.0010) * 100
    }
    one.css(one_css);

    ++two_start;
    var two_css = {
        'left': Math.sin(two_start * 0.0025) * 200 ,
        'top': Math.cos(two_start * 0.0025) * 200
    }
    two.css(two_css);
}, 1);
```

But he does not do it exactly, but like it a zigzag.

How to make sure that the element did clean circle?

Comment: It looks fine to me. What browser are you running?

Comment: What do you mean by zigzag?

Comment: It looks better when animation is done with `setTimeout`, or maybe even `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/HDhn4/6/ , this better saw a bug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use jQuery.

The problem is that positions are rounded to the nearest pixel, meaning the shapes cannot follow an exact circle.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HDhn4/4/) is a CSS3-only reproduction of your animation. By using a `transform`, the effect is not constrained to integer pixel values and can therefore follow your circle perfectly.

Comment: The `0.0010` and `0.0025` are scaling factors, not an attempt to convert deg2rad...

Comment: @Kolink my bad. I had *just* answered a question for deg2rad so I guess I still had that on my mind making the numbers conflict :-)

Comment: How would you make them go at diff speeds?

Comment: @DevlshOne That would require animating the two circles individually. I took a shortcut and rotated the whole "canvas", but it wouldn't be particularly hard to animate each circle individually.

Comment: I'm thinking a solar system re-creation with active eclipses.

Answer (score 3):

This is in part caused by rounding-errors as plain CSS only deals with integer positions (see kolink's or Jonas' transform examples to enable fractional values).

If transform is not an option you can improve the rounding error by reducing the problem a little by "helping" the browser to round off correctly, either by adding `0.5` at the end:

```
'left': Math.sin(one_start * 0.001) * 100 +0.5,
'top': Math.cos(one_start * 0.001) * 100 +0.5
```

or using `Math.round()`:

```
'left': Math.round(Math.sin(one_start * 0.001) * 100),
'top': Math.round(Math.cos(one_start * 0.001) * 100)
```

**[See here for modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/HDhn4/8/)**.

Optionally you can also use a `canvas` element which supports sub-pixeling. This means your fractional positions will be rendered (interpolated/anti-aliased) and show a much smoother result (as with transformations) but with the flexibility that comes with the territory. However, CSS will be faster at rendering so if you don't need the (artistic) flexibility CSS is a better choice.

PS: the center is off. You can adjust: x - radius, y - radius and they will be in the correct position.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the sub-pixel rendering, using transforms instead of "top" and "left" should solve the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/HDhn4/2/

```
var one_css = {
    'transform': "translateX(" + (Math.sin(one_start * 0.0025) * 100) + 'px) translateY('+ Math.cos(one_start * 0.0025) * 100 + "px)"
}
```

This solution is not yet cross-browser, you might need to add css prefixed for that.

Also, read this:

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

PS: note that I only applied it to the red ball, so you can see the difference

Comment: For a cross-browser solution, consider using `left` and `top` with `Math.floor` to round the numbers, then apply the `transform` using `%1` to handle the fractional adjustment. The animation may continue to appear "zig-zaggy" in older browsers, but will at least work ^_^